# put gallery above linear layout in frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In a frame layout there is a linear layout that contains a linear layout and a gallery. i want to place gallery above that linaer "buttons" but is at the bottom of layout.

[picture of layout. click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDOLP.png)

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/front"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="matrix"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:background="#ffffff" android:alpha="0.5"/>





    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Gallery
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:spacing="10px"  />




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="one" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="two" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:text="three" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: FrameLayout is supposed to have a single child, in your case, frameLayout contains 4 childs, 3 images and one linearlayout, which is wrong.

Comment: why it is wrong? I need two imageviews in frame layout that fill the windows so that I can merge them. buttons and gallery should be placed over them.

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Gallery
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Gallery>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not work. I want the frame layout be the background. your code will separate frame layout and other layout.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="matrix" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:spacing="10px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="one" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="two" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="three" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put gallery in the linear layout and it works:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <Gallery
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/examplegallery"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:spacing="10px" />
        </LinearLayout>
```